# Not able to login while using Opera Mobile created using Jquery

Tags: jquery-mobile, opera

While using Opera mobile browser my login page i can enter data in username and passwd fields but not able to fire any event so that i can direct the application to another page.

Same app is working fine with Android browser. A 'Go' key appears on it while entering the data, on pressing that key it fires ENTER event(i checked the key code : 13).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share a URL to a test case so we can have a look?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the onscreen "enter" key to fire the event? This is a problem with the Android Opera Mobile browser, and can be seen on many sites including stackoverflow (try searching -- fine with the stock browser but impossible with Opera). You can avoid the problem by adding a "Go" button to the page itself.